# How to run Visual Studio Test task in a app context (a certain service principle)

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a build task in Azure DevOps  build that has to execute a bunch of functional tests. To do that, the code has to download some secrets from the key vault. Now my key vault code supports only service principle based authentication. 
How can I execute my functional tests (I am using Visual Studio Test Task for the same) using a certain service principle in my AAD so that authentication to key vault does not fail?

Comment: are you looking for guidance about how to access the key vault in your function tests using a service principle?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, although it is possible to create an Azure Resource Manager service connection with an existing service principal, the [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops#arguments) does not define any arguments for accepting Service connections. But you might want to consider exploring the following alternate options to support your current configuration:

- [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) task: Can be used to fetch all or a subset of secrets from the vault, and set them as variables that can be used in subsequent tasks of a pipeline.
- [Define secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables): Scoped to the pipeline in which you set
  them; note the caveats.
- Configure [Variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic): Can be used to share variables across multiple pipelines in your project.
- [Link secrets from an Azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault): Link an existing Azure key vault to a variable group and map selective vault secrets to the variable group.

Check the following blog posts for a detailed walkthrough:

- https://zimmergren.net/using-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-azure-devops-pipeline/
- https://www.dotnetcurry.com/devops/1507/azure-key-vault-secrets-pipelines

Hope this helps!